# как совместить httpbasic и formlogin в spring security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

В spring boot приложении есть api часть и интерфейс на vaadin. Хочу для api настроить http basic, а для интерфейса formlogin. в данном варианте работает только http basic, а formlogin не принимает логин-пароль

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.requestCache()
                .requestCache(new CustomRequestCache())
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/configuration/**",
                        "/swagger*/**",
                        "/console/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).hasAnyRole(COMMITTEE_MEMBER,BUSINESS_ADMINISTRATOR)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE).denyAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.HEAD).denyAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).denyAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH).denyAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).denyAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT).denyAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.TRACE).denyAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), userRepository))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage(LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL)
                .failureUrl(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL)
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL);
    }

protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("******"))
            .roles(ADMINISTRATOR);
}

    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user =
            User.withUsername("admin")
                    .password("{noop}*******")
                    .roles(ADMINISTRATOR)
                    .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
```

Как настроить их на совместную деятельность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доступ к разным компонентам системы с разными параметрами безопасности настраивается путем создания нескольких бинов - наследников WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. В примере ниже создается 2 конфигурации: 1-ая - с доступом в систему пользователей из БД с jwt-токеном, 2-ая - публичный доступ без авторизации.

**Конфигурация 1**

```java
@Order(102)
@Configuration
public class PrivateConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public PrivateConfig(
            JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider,
            @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl") UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Primary
    @Override
    @Bean(name = "authenticationManagerBeanGENERIC")
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Выключить простую аутентификацию
        http.httpBasic().disable();

        // CSRF & CORS
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors();

        // Взаимодействие без сохранения состояния
        // Сессию создавать не надо
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Правила проверки
        http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/profiles/forms").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/profiles/*").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/account/me").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/account/logout").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER")
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("USER"); // Доступ к REST API только для пользователей

        // Фильтря для JWT-аутентификации
        JwtTokenFilter filter = new JwtTokenFilter(jwtTokenProvider);
        http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

**Конфигурация 2**

```java
@Order(100)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class PublicConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] ANT_PATTERNS = {
            "/api/public/**",
            "/api/dictionaries/**",
            "/api/registration/**",
            "/api/account/login",
            "/api/account/password/reset/**",
            "/api/account/confirm",
            "/api/search/egrul",
            "/api/search/credentials"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Выключить простую аутентификацию
        http.httpBasic().disable();

        // CSRF & CORS
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors();

        // Взаимодействие без сохранения состояния
        // Сессию создавать не надо
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Правила проверки
        http.requestMatchers(requestMatcherConfigurer -> requestMatcherConfigurer.antMatchers(ANT_PATTERNS))
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
    }

}
```

При этом нужно понимать:

1. Конфигурации должны быть разграничены по области применения путем указания для каких компонентов системы они должны срабатывать. В примере выше это реализуется через `http.antMatcher(...)` и `http.requestMathcers(...)`.
2. Необходимо явно указать приоритет проверки конфигурации. Хорошим практикой считается назначение приоритета в зависимости от размера области действия: чем большую область действия (больше компонент) охватывает конфигурация, тем позднее она должна отрабать и тем большее значение приоритета необходимо указать. В примере выше проверки по `PublicConfig` выполняются раньше, чем `PrivateConfig`